# How can i get the selected row of the datatable in jsf page?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, datatable, radio-button

I have a datatable filled from the database and have a radio button at each row. Here is my code:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"  /> 
     <script>
         // <![CDATA[
            function dataTableSelectOneRadio(radio) {
                var id = radio.name.substring(radio.name.lastIndexOf(':'));
                var el = radio.form.elements;
                for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                    if (el[i].name.substring(el[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) == id) {
                        el[i].checked = false;
                    }
                }
                radio.checked = true;
            }
            // ]]>
        </script>
</h:head>
<h:body>


    <h:form>
        <rich:dataTable   id="userTable" value="#{user.info}" var="info" >
            <rich:column>
                <h:selectOneRadio  onchange="dataTableSelectOneRadio(this);"  >
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="null" itemLabel="{#xxx.propertname}"/>
                </h:selectOneRadio>
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">User Name</f:facet>
                    #{user.username}
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                    #{user.name}
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Surname</f:facet>
                    #{user.surname}
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Age</f:facet>
                    #{user.age}
            </rich:column>
        </rich:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

My question is, after selecting a row with a radio button, how can i get the value of this row, i.e. how can i get the age, name etc. attributes of the selected row?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know of the client/server distinction? Basic HTML/JS and JSF? Do you understand how to get a help on specific issue in these technologies? If you did, you'd answer your question by yourself.

Comment: Instead of behaving like a group of toddlers with your colleague(s) (@BigO) with your pity downvotes you'd better listen to the advice given. Be sure to ask a concrete question after having investigated everything on your own. You will never become professionals in case every smallest step if yours is solved by enthusiasts like people here on SO who spend their time to assist people who need help...

Comment: ...But help can be different. We know how to do it, but it won't help you. Best of luck and be sure to consult [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) next time you'll make a post.